# Polarize light after double slit experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, laser, double-slit-experiment, polarization

Recently, I and a classmate did the double slit experiment in class with a laser, but since we had a polarizer (circular if it matters), we placed it after the double slit, and we observed an interesting pattern. There were two interference patterns on the screen, one of them was horizontal and the other was vertical. So I though about it, and it does not really make sense. What happened to produce this pattern?

Comment: Did the presence of the polarizer effect the interference pattern that you saw? What did you see before/after putting in the polarizer?

Comment: The interference pattern before the polarizer was a normal double slit interference pattern. When we added the polarizer after the double slit, there was a mirrored image of the pattern, but going through the middle of the horizontal interference pattern,and the light was weaker than the light of the normal pattern. Could it be because of imperfections on the polarizer or from the strength of the laser?

Comment: This question does not contain enough information to give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

After the light wave passes through the double slit, it becomes two waves that are in phase. After you apply the circular polarizer, one wave stays the same, but the other shifts. This will double in interference pattern depending on the angle you tilt the polarizer, and another zebra pattern will appear.

The two waves that are now out of phase, and since they are polarized in the same direction by the double slit, the wave that will be visible is the sum of the two waves, and since they are out of phase, their sum will cause the second interference pattern you see, which is caused by the circular polarization of the light wave.

Comment: Why would the polarizer act differently on the two portions of the wave?